# Problem with running CXF on Weblogic 10.3.5 /w SOA server

Tags: java, web-services, soa, cxf, weblogic-10.x

I deployed a CXF Web Service war file on a Weblogic 10.3.5 with OracleSOA server, and I got following exceptions. I tested the war file on another Weblogic without OracleSOA without server and work fine.

```
<Jul 28, 2011 3:08:31 PM HKT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.soap.SOAPBindingImpl.getElementType()
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ExtensionInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtensionInvocationHandler.java:41)
        at $Proxy607.getElementType(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsEndpointImpl.hasUsingAddressing(JaxWsEndpointImpl.java:240)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsEndpointImpl.extractWsdlExtensibilities(JaxWsEndpointImpl.java:201)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jul 28, 2011 3:08:31 PM HKT> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.soap.SOAPBindingImpl.getElementType()
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ExtensionInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtensionInvocationHandler.java:41)
        at $Proxy607.getElementType(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsEndpointImpl.hasUsingAddressing(JaxWsEndpointImpl.java:240)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsEndpointImpl.extractWsdlExtensibilities(JaxWsEndpointImpl.java:201)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsEndpointImpl.<init>(JaxWsEndpointImpl.java:191)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.createEndpoint(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:235)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:166)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:202)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:433)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:322)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:509)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
```

I have added following lines to weblogic.xml, but can't fix the problem:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

How to fix this problem, because the war file suppose deploy on the SOA Weblogic server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package the juddiv3 plus cxf war as an ear

Add the following deployment descriptors to the ear
file "META-INF/application.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="5"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
  <display-name>juddiv3</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>juddiv3</web-uri>
      <context-root>juddiv3</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

file "META.INF/weblogic-application.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">
  <wls:application-param>
    <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
    <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
  </wls:application-param>
  <wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>javax.wsdl.*</wls:package-name>
    <!-- If using hibernate also add this 
    <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
    -->
  </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Answer (score 1):

A [similar issue reported with CXF and Weblogic 10.3.3](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/java-lang-NoSuchMethodException-oracle-j2ee-See-the-message-td3275013.html) says the error is because Oracle loads it's own `wsdl4j` and instead use one from within your war. Is `wsdl4j` jar present in the WEB-INF/lib of your war?

Only then will wls:prefer-web-inf-classes be effective.

Otherwise [CXF recommends packaging your war](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-Packwarinanear,deploytheearwithweblogicapplication.xml) as an ear on Weblogic, add a `weblogic-application.xml` (Weblogic specific) in the `META-INF` folder and using

```
<prefer-application-packages>
```

Can you try the first approach and then the second?